# How does JBoss 7.1.1 manage connection to different schemas of the same database

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, schema, datasource

So I have a servlet where I login to a database with Datasource(where I only pass the JNDI name) with a default schema(which was set in the JBoss management console) but later on I need to connect on the same database with another schema in order to get some texts.

How does JBoss manage this ? Can I provide the later schema and password somehow in the java code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

În standalone.xml you declare all your datasources. Those connections can be picked up by jndi at runtime by looking up on an InitialContext instance.

Answer (score 0):

When using JNDI to form connections, you will need to configure the new datasource within the management console or the standalone.xml file. This will simply be a new datasource, with a connection URL going to the same database, but pointing to a new schema.

Example output in the standalone.xml:

```
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/firstDS" pool-name="firstDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@devdb:1521:SCHEMA_1</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
...
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/secondDS" pool-name="secondDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@devdb:1521:SCHEMA_2</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
```

Now in the second part of your application you will just refer to that second datasource's JNDI name when forming the connection.